# What's the difference between the methods when we create typed dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

HI
When we create typed dataset in .Net, we can choose 2 methods. One is **Fill a DataTable** and another is **Return a DataTable**. What's the difference between those two? Can anybody give me some good explanation on it ? Sorry about my ignorance.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Table Adapters: Get vs. Fill?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172436/net-table-adapters-get-vs-fill)

Comment: @Dillie >> Thanks . I search it first but somehow I don't see it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its been a long time since I've worked with typed datasets, but from what i remember the difference between the two is:
"Returns a DataTable" returns a new instance of the DataTable object.
"Fills a DataTable" takes in an object you already have and fills the results with it.

Comment: @jay >> So can I choose anyone I like ?

Comment: Yes! the MS guys put them both there, because we programmers like to have options. Again, its been a very long time (I've since moved on to the entity framework), but if you already have an object perhaps with some data in it, and you just want to add, use fill. Or if its just a quick grab of data, returning a DataTable works well.

Comment: @jay >> Thx again . one more question ,does entity framework is better than typed dataset ?In which aspects,  it's better ? Sorry again about my ignorance.

Comment: @kevin> No problem at all take a look here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(v=vs.80).aspx) The entity framework is much newer and provides a higher level of abstraction to the data layer than typed datasets. This means, through the use of Linq you do not have to write any SQL. The framework builds classes from an existing database and creates a set of objects you can use. Either way you never have to deal with the sql, but can access the objects as if they were already filled with data. The framework does all the heavy lifting for you

Comment: No problem! Good luck to you!